# Write a pseudo code for a Graph algorithm

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

Given a DAG [image] and a function [image] which maps every vertex to a unique number from 1 to [image], I need to write a pseudo code for an algorithm that finds for every [image] the minimal value of [image], among all vertices u that are reachable from v, and save it a an attribute of v. The time complexity of the algorithm needs to be [image] (assuming that time complexity of [image] is [image]).

I thought about using DFS (or a variation of it) and/or topological sort, but I don't know how to use it in order to solve this problem.

In addition, I need to think about an algorithm that gets an undirected graph and the function [image], and calculate the same thing for every vertex, and I don't know how to do it either.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of using DFS is right. Actually the function `f(v)` is only given for saying that each node can be uniquely identified from a number between 1 and `|V|`.

Just a hint for solving, you would have to modify DFS so that it returns the minimum value of `f(v)` of the vertex `v` reachable from this node and save it another array, let's say `minReach` and the index would be given by the function `f(v)`. The visited array `vis` would similarly be identified using `f(v)`.

I am also giving the pseudocode if you are not able to solve but try on your own first.
The pseudocode is similar to python and assuming the graph and function `f(v)` are available. And 0-based indexing is assumed.

```
vis=[0, 0, 0, .. |V| times]  # visited array for dfs 
minReach= [1, 2, 3, .. |V| times] #  array for storing no. reachable nodes from a node

function dfs(node):
   vis[f(node)-1]=1                             ### mark unvisited node as visited 
   for v in graph[node]:
       if vis[v]!=1:                            ## check whether adjacent node is visited
           minReach[f(node)-1]=min(minReach[f(node)-1],dfs(v)        ## if not visited apply dfs again
       else:
           minReach[f(node)-1]=min(minReach[f(node)-1],countReach[f(v)-1])   ## else store the minimum node that can be reached from this node.
   return countReach[f(node)-1]

for vertex in graph:         ### each vertex is checked in graph
   if vis[f(vertex)-1]!=1:   ### if vertex is not visited dfs is applied
      dfs(vertex)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the algorithm needs to find the minimal value of f(u), among all among all vertices u that are reachable from v, and not counting how many vertices are reachable

Comment: How can I extend it into a cyclic directed graph (not DAG)?

Comment: I think this should work in case of cyclic directed graphs too. Because for cyclic graphs as there would be a back-edge where we are visiting a node which has already been visited. This case is when `vis[v]=1` for a neighbour which is handled. If you find an example where it might not then please comment.

Comment: please accept the answer if you are satisfied